# Hg: Which changeset is newer?

Tags: mercurial

Given two hg changeset ids (e.g., `891d791429ab`, `24797c841ee6`), is there an hg command that will tell me which changeset is newer, where newer is defined as 'closer to tip'?

I'd rather not use revision number or date.

**Edit**:

This is how I would intuitively define 'newer'. I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that hg has some internal definition of the concept.

[image: hg commits]

I assume that if there is no way to reach one of the compared commits by traversing the DAG, then those commits cannot have an order, so the order of **B** and **C** is undefined.

As for merged commits, e.g., **G** and **H** after **I**, If Hg applies **G** and **H** in some linear order to form **I**, presumably **G** and **H** should have an order after they are merged in **I**. But I don't know what that is. For my purposes treating them as equally new is certainly acceptable.

With my apologies for being unclear.

Comment: I might have answered based on misunderstanding your definition of _newer_. Do you mean, as I think Lazy Badger understood it, shortest distance in graph terms? E.g. if `tip` is a merge results, both parents are equally 'new'. Also if one changeset is an ancestor of `tip` and the other  isn't, will the ancestor always be newer? E.g. if `A` -> `B` -> `C` -> `tip` and `B` -> `D`, is there any situation where `D` might be newer than `A`,  `B` or `C`?

Comment: Indeed, it seems I failed to address several scenarios in my problem definition. I'll attempt to clarify with an edit.

Comment: Ok, can **now** your question be redefined as "identify who is whose ancestor?"

Comment: @LazyBadger I didn't *want* to define it that way, but perhaps that's all you can ask when dealing with the DAG?

Comment: Ancestry is trivial, and may be used to get a better solution. Depends on _why_ you need to determine this, I guess. I was toying with a variant of @LazyBadger's suggestion: `hg log --template '.' -r ancestor($1,tip)::tip|hg log --template '.' -r ancestor($1,tip)::$1`. It's not quite what you asked for: A is 'newer' than C, but one could make the case that C is actually further from tip than A is. Or, if you pipe the two above separately to `wc -c`, you can subtract, so C's distance from path is `len(A,tip)-len(A,C)` and B and C should be equally far from tip, and it should always work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I can't recall predefined command(s) for exactly such task
- I suppose, it can be done with (have to be written) extension rather easy
- Fast and dirty way - `[alias]` for something like `log -r $1::tip` -T "."` (longer line of dots - more distance)

Comment: So this command prints one dot for each revision between `$1` and tip, and you'd then just compare the number of dots generated by different revisions? Interesting.

Comment: @ForeverWintr - in case of good OS (or GOW in Win) alias can be converted to shell-alias for more readable result `$HG log $1::tip -T "." | wc -c` and output *numeric distance*

Comment: Could you also compare the two revisions to each other? `log -r $1::$2 -T "."`. If you get any result, `$1` is newer, else `$2` is newer or the changesets are on different branches.

Comment: @ForeverWintr - yes, I could. But with DAG it's dirty solution (due to "or")

Comment: I think this is the best answer based on the question. It gives you the relative distance of each commit from tip. However, the question is flawed, because the relative distance of unrelated commits is really meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

How about `hg id -r "(891d791429ab|24797c841ee6)-((891d791429ab:tip-24797c841ee6:tip)|(24797c841ee6:tip-891d791429ab:tip))"`?

The revset can be simplified to `(A|B)-((A:tip-B:tip)|(B:tip-A:tip))`

One of `((A:tip-B:tip)` or `(B:tip-A:tip))` will be empty. The other will contain either `A` or `B`, whichever is further from `tip` (plus any changesets *between* `A` and `B`).

When we subtract this revset that contains the furthest-from-tip changeset from the union `A|B`, we end up with the changeset that is nearest the tip

Comment: I'm getting syntax errors on the brackets. Is this syntax new? I'm using hg `3.7.3` on ubuntu.

Comment: With first (long) form of revset I got **farest** changeset, not nearest

Comment: @ForeverWintr I tested this in tortoisehg on windows. Can you try enclosing the whole revset in quotation marks as per my edited post?

Comment: Adding quotation marks addressed the issue, thanks. Interestingly, your solution seems to apply an ordering to changesets from different branches (**B** and **C** from my question). But I don't understand how it's doing that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @SigveKolbeinson, after doing some reading about revsets, my understanding is that `A:B` gets changesets between A and B based on *revision number*. Doesn't that mean that your command could yield different results on different clones of the repo?

Comment: Yes it does, I was going to edit based on the edited question, but I haven't had time to do so yet. Hope to do so later today.